# How to convert URL to URI in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

im really confuse here, i have URL and i want to convert it to URI ,
URL : http://localhost:30352/img/icon/Ae9CC0dVgkiFzszgDY81Lg.jpg 
what i want is a method that convert to this :
c:\proj1\img\icon\Ae9CC0dVgkiFzszgDY81Lg.jpg
is there any class or something like that to convert ?
i already used Path class but it wont return when i tried to use GetFullPath method**strong text**

Comment: Maybe ToString() your url then you could use Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");

Comment: Have a look at [Server.MapPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.8), that should do what you want (if I understood the question right)...

Comment: I tried Uri and MapPath and they dose not support URL, i was looking for specific method that can convert , but seems it dosen't exist, so i made my own method.